# iOS - Adding multiple targets to the same project?

Tags: ios, xcode

I am trying to add 3 targets to my existing project. Dev, QA, and Prod.
The problem is that when I rename the target, during the build it looks for the target name as my project root folder, so I get a bunch of build error because all my header search path, library search paths are now broke.

Is it possible to make it so that Xcode uses the same project root name regardless of what the target name is?

Comment: Why exactly do you need separate targets? Take a look at schemes, you can probably do whatever you need to using them and multiple build configurations.

Comment: @FilipRadelic I have a config.plist that contain all the info about server ip, port, timeouts, analytics ID, etc. Instead of manually changing these values each time, I am trying to create 3 config files and add each one to 1 target. That way all I have to do is to select the target, and everything else will be automated.

Comment: You can do that using schemes and get rid of problems that you have with targets. Create separate build configurations for each "target" and create multiple schemes, each using its respective build configuration. Then under build settings you can set a separate info.plist file for each configuration. Would that work for you?

Comment: @FilipRadelic I know how to create schemes, the problem is duplicating and building multiple targets first

Comment: I'm saying you don't *need* multiple targets, you can do what you want to do using schemes.

Comment: @FilipRadelic Some detail or a link would be great. I did some searching and I did not find any way to assign different plist files to different schemes

Comment: @FilipRadelic Now I get what you mean. But that doesn't work for me, because build settings are limited. I have multiple plists

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out what the problem was: $(SRCROOT)/$(PRODUCT_NAME) in my frameworks search path. $PRODUCT_NAME is being used to find the root directory of the project, and since all the targets are pointing to the same project I ended up hard-coing the project name. $(SRCROOT)/MyProject.

Answer (score 0):

Did you change the name in the box below? I had similar problems with names getting out of kilt, and it turned out this was the key if I recall. I should add if you have one target and want to duplicate it, you can select the one, then right click and get a duplicate contextual menu.

[image]

EDIT: Then, go to the Manage Schemes and make sure the name is correct there, and not "Project Copy". If all else fails grep you project in Terminal looking for "Copy" - you might have to edit the project file with vi (with it closed in Xcode!)

Comment: Thanks David, That's exactly how I created the target, and renamed it. By creating a duplicate of an already existing one

Comment: I found the problem I had, but not the solution. When you duplicate, it makes a project called "Searcher Copy". There is a bug (and I have a rdar// on it) where the build system breaks if there is a space in the target name. So you rename the "Searcher Project" to "Foo". But it doesn't really take - if you go to Manage schemes, you will still see the Searcher Copy name. So you have to not only rename it here but look for the " Copy" elsewhere. Sigh. I fixed this before but I can't see to figure it out now...Hah the second time it worked correctly.

Comment: I found out what the problem was: $(SRCROOT)/$(PRODUCT_NAME) in my frameworks search path. $PRODUCT_NAME is being used to find the root directory of the project, and since all the targets are pointing to the same project I ended up hard-coing the project name. $(SRCROOT)/MyProject.

Comment: You should create an answer, then accept it, to close this out. Glad you found it!